# How to trim strings in database?

Tags: sql, string, trim

I have a database table (named firsttable )with words and scores like this

```
words     score
book's      2
book        5
pen         4
bag         6
books       7
```

What I want to do is, since book is root for book's and books I would like to delete book's and books from table and add their score on word book.However for words like copy-copies-copy's it wont work.but it doesnt matter. and at the end I would like to have database table like this

```
words     score

book        14
pen         4
bag         6
```

Is it possible*

Comment: Which SQL dialect? How do you determine which words to merge - e.g. why didn't you also add together "book" and "bag" since they both start with "b"?

Comment: What about "Theater", "Theory" and "the"? Are they all reduced to "the"?

Comment: Its impossible to do without some rules, you have to determine a way to know which words relates to what. I can suggest creating a temp table containing two columns, root and child, and add the relations to it yourself, then use it to do your request.

Comment: Can't I use a function like contain? the rule is if any word(not part of word!) in array is contained by other word then kep the word and delete others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a wildcard % for the suffix to the word book. Something like...

```
SELECT score FROM MyTable where words LIKE book%
```

Comment: cant we generalize this statement for all database because book was just an example that i gave

Comment: To find your word roots you could use `SELECT LEFT (words , 3) FROM MyTable`. If set at 3 this would add boots to the same query as books, but if set at 4, you would have problems with pen.

Answer (score 0):

It's always very tricky to play with plural words and then group them under their singular forms. I had once written a function which helped me get out singulars.

```
IF(RIGHT(@input, 2) = 'es')
    SELECT LEFT(@input, LEN(@input) - CHARINDEX('es', REVERSE(@input)))
ELSE IF (RIGHT(@input, 1) = 's')
    SELECT LEFT(@input, LEN(@input) - CHARINDEX('s', REVERSE(@input)))
```

There are exceptions for words ending with 's' or 'es' but would work fine for your books.